# Is there a way to get the designer view in the JMC 8 to visualize the event?

Tags: plugins, visualization, graph-visualization, jfr, jmc

In the older version of JMC (I guess till JMC 5) we had the designer view to visualize the events. How can I achieve the same functionality in JMC 8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Designer View was removed in JMC 6.

You can still create custom views by right-clicking on Event Browser in the Outline view and select New Page -> Custom Page ... It's not as powerful, but you can create you own custom histograms and tables.